# Postgresql create table condition exclude one column in tsrange

Tags: postgresql, conditional-statements, create-table

I want to define a table with a constraint.
the data is: "article_name,article_time,start_time,end_time"

for the moment I use this condition:

```
EXCLUDE USING gist (article_name WITH =,
            tsrange(start_time,end_time) WITH &&)
```

but that means to not take any new row for which the range overlaps 
with an existing range with the same article_name, whereas I want to change it to get:

don't take new rows for which article_time is inside an existing range (start_time,end_time), 
for the same article_name

How can I declare that please?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that you can't use `<@` or `@>`, I think you need a trigger here with smth like

```
IF
 (
 SELECT count(1) 
 FROM table_name
 WHERE article_name = NEW. article_name
  AND NOT tsrange(NEW. start_time,NEW. end_time) <@ tsrange(start_time, end_time)
 ) < 1 
THEN
 return NEW;
END IF;
```